# Traffic NGIX to several backends

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I saw many questions and answers for same subject but I'm still not convinced about my use case.

In my topology I have:

- One server with NGINX / FastCGI for Wordpress multisite (subdomains)
- One server with NGINX / FastCGI for API's (written in PHP)
- One server with NGIX proxying a NodeJS app for socket connections

This is all using same domain name. Each server with its own public IP

For Wordpress, it manages itself the subdomains redirections.

For API's I also have subdomains for each API `server { listen 80; server_name sub.xx.com....`

For NodeJS is just an Upstream

Is that possible to concentrate all requests into one IP, thus one NGINX, and let this guy dispatch the requests for the right server ?
The back servers need to have NGINX too ?

The question states mainly on Wordpress multisite and non-php content being served by a third server, as for `fast_cgi` I can proxy_pass to my `fast_cgi` instance IP:Port on back server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - **Yes**. You could configure multiple domains on one nginx frontend and forward all requests to one or more backends.

Comment: Thanks ! Do I need Nginx on backend servers that serves static files ?

Comment: @GIJOW yes, nginx or another web-server.

Comment: Perfect. At least now I know what I have to research. Thank you